# Chrome automatic login

Tags: google-chrome, vba

Is there a command line switch for chrome to automatically log a user into his google drive ? I am building an Excel Addin and running the shell command to open chrome and display the google drive login. Or maybe there is another way using a script maybe. It would be nice if this can be done in the background. Here is the command.

Shell ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe -url https:drive.google.com")

Answer (score 0):

[The current list of command line options](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/). A quick ctrl+f for "drive" indicates that the answer is unfortunately no.